# Mockito: How do I verify that the array passed to my method contains the right object?

Tags: java, junit, arguments, mockito, verify

I’m using Mockito 1.9.5.  I want to verify that my method (which takes an array as a param) was called in which the array contains exactly one specific object.  I’m having trouble figuring out how to do this.  I have

```
Mockito.doReturn(new SaveResult[]{}).when(mockConnection).update(org.mockito.Matchers.any(SObject[].class));
…     

Mockito.verify(mockConnection, Mockito.times(1)).update( new Account[]{ acct });
```

Unsurprisingly, the second line fails because although the argument, “acct” is the same as what is passed, the enclosing array is not.  What is the best way to check for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mockito has a builtin matcher, [`AdditionalMatchaer#aryEq(T[])`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#aryEq(T%5B%5D)) for this usecase exactly:

```
Mockito.verify(mockConnection, Mockito.times(1))
       .update(aryEq(new Account[]{ acct }));
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Mockito's built-in `aryEq()` matcher, you can use `argThat()` with one of Hamcrest's array Matchers. The [arrayContaining](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#arrayContaining(E...)) matcher is a good starting point.

Note that in modern versions of Mockito (newer than 2.1.0 in Sept 2016), you'll need to use [MockitoHamcrest.argThat](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.3.1/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html); [ArgumentMatchers.argThat](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.3.1/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat-org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher-) (exposed via static inheritance as Mockito.argThat) no longer depends on Hamcrest. This avoids a version dependency between Hamcrest and Mockito's core files.

Though MockitoHamcrest was considered for separation/deprecation/deletion in 2019 (see [mockito#1817](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1817) and [mockito#1819](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/1819)) the file still exists without visible deprecation [as of v4.3.1 in January 2022](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v4.3.1/src/main/java/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.java). ArgumentMatchers.argThat is still preferable for lambdas and small custom implementations, but to use [Hamcrest's extensive built-in matcher library](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) you'll need MockitoHamcrest as an adapter (or you'll need to adapt it yourself via ArgumentMatchers.argThat).

Comment: I want to clarify that the `argThat` method being referred to needs to come from the `MockitoHamcrest` package in order to be able to accept Hamcrest matchers as an argument. My IDE defaulted to `ArgumentMatchers.argThat` which does not accept Hamcrest matchers.

Comment: @kenset I've updated the answer, so it should be correct to 2022's library structure. Thanks for the nudge.